# Getting null from get request but context returns value

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor-server-side

My back end that returns items from the database looks like this

```
    // GET: api/Members
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Members>>> GetMembers()
    {
        return await _context.Members.ToArrayAsync();
    }
```

And can confirm I am getting data

[image]

My get hits this end point

```
private async Task GetMembers()
{
    _members = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Members[]>("api/Members");
}
```

But I get null from "members"
"members" is an array

```
private Members[] _members;
```

This is me getting null

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: members and _members are the same reference in picture and post

Comment: How have you setup your HttpClient to call your API method? Can you show us that?

Comment: @RahulSharma Since this is Blazor, I am just injecting it. "@inject HttpClient Http"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was having problems with the Blazor http injection so I injected the service as a scoped service

```
services.AddScoped<MembersService>();
```

Then changed the backend service

```
//GET: api/MembersService
[HttpGet]
public async Task<List<Members>> GetMembersAsync()
{
     return new List<Members>(_context.members);
}
```

Note that I need an await in there.

Then on the client,

```
private async Task GetMembers()
{
    _members = await memberService.GetMembersAsync();
}
```

The _members is a list

```
private List<Members> _members;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your htttp resquests doesn't work. You should try to use HttpClient for the resquest and do something like this:

```cs
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("yourtUrl");

Members [] members = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Members[]>();
```

Comment: Thanks! I am still getting null with the new http method you proposed

Comment: If you're a getting NullException might your call is not retuning what you members expected, or de api you calling is returning a error, you can check te api return ?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not getting NullException, I am getting null as in no data in the context...The backend is returning the data fine, the front end is getting null